# AttributeError: 'KMeansFeaturizer' object has no attribute 'km_model'

Tags: python, классы, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

При обращении к классу:

```
kmf_hint = KMeansFeaturizer(k=100, target_scale=10, random_state=seed).fit(X_train)
training_cluster_features = kmf_hint.transform(X_train)
```

получаю ошибку

> AttributeError: 'KMeansFeaturizer' object has no attribute 'km_model'

Возможно кто-то разглядит в чем моя проблема?

```
class KMeansFeaturizer:

    def __init__(self, k=100, target_scale=5.0, random_state=None):
        self.k = k
        self.target_scale = target_scale
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.cluster_encoder = OneHotEncoder().fit(np.array(range(k)).reshape(-1,1))

    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        if y is None:
            # No target variable, just do plain k-means
            km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                              n_init=20, 
                              random_state=self.random_state)
            km_model.fit(X)

            self.km_model_ = km_model
            self.cluster_centers_ = km_model.cluster_centers_
            return self

        data_with_target = np.hstack((X, y[:,np.newaxis]*self.target_scale))

        # Build a pre-training k-means model on data and target
        km_model_pretrain = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                                   n_init=20, 
                                   random_state=self.random_state)
        km_model_pretrain.fit(data_with_target)

        km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                          init=km_model_pretrain.cluster_centers_[:,:2], 
                          n_init=1, 
                          max_iter=1)
        km_model.fit(X)

        self.km_model = km_model
        self.cluster_centers_ = km_model.cluster_centers_
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

        clusters = self.km_model.predict(X)
        return self.cluster_encoder.transform(clusters.reshape(-1,1))

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):

        self.fit(X, y)
        return self.transform(X, y)
```

Если нужны какие-то комментарии по коду, то попробую объяснить.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-c66249a58f92> in <module>()
----> 1 training_cluster_features = kmf_hint.transform(X_train)
      2 test_cluster_features = kmf_hint.transform(X_test)
 <ipython-input-10-cfff875862c6> in transform(self, X, y)
    105         cluster_ids : array, shape[n_data_points,1]
    106         """
--> 107         clusters = self.km_model.predict(X)
    108         return self.cluster_encoder.transform(clusters.reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: на какой строке кода возникает `exception`? `clusters = self.km_model.predict(X)` ?

Comment: @MaxU      
   --> 107         clusters = self.km_model.predict(X)
         108         return self.cluster_encoder.transform(clusters.reshape(-1,1))

Comment: никак не могу красиво вывести сюда построчно ответ

Comment: А сюда, то есть в комментарий, и не надо. [Правте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1024394/edit) вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class KMeansFeaturizer:

    def __init__(self, k=100, target_scale=5.0, random_state=None):
        self.k = k
        self.target_scale = target_scale
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.cluster_encoder = OneHotEncoder().fit(np.array(range(k)).reshape(-1,1))
        self.km_model = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        if y is None:
            # No target variable, just do plain k-means
            self.km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                              n_init=20, 
                              random_state=self.random_state)
            self.km_model.fit(X)

            self.cluster_centers_ = self.km_model.cluster_centers_
            return self

        data_with_target = np.hstack((X, y[:,np.newaxis]*self.target_scale))

        # Build a pre-training k-means model on data and target
        km_model_pretrain = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                                   n_init=20, 
                                   random_state=self.random_state)
        km_model_pretrain.fit(data_with_target)

        self.km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, 
                          init=km_model_pretrain.cluster_centers_[:,:2], 
                          n_init=1, 
                          max_iter=1)
        self.km_model.fit(X)
        self.cluster_centers_ = self.km_model.cluster_centers_
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

        clusters = self.km_model.predict(X)
        return self.cluster_encoder.transform(clusters.reshape(-1,1))

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):

        self.fit(X, y)
        return self.transform(X, y)
```

Проверка:

```
In [74]: kmf_hint = KMeansFeaturizer(k=100, target_scale=10, random_state=seed).fit(X_train)

In [75]: training_cluster_features = kmf_hint.transform(X_train)

In [76]: training_cluster_features
Out[76]:
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: нашел откуда ноги растут, если указываю y, то все работает, без него ошибка

Comment: пока исключил блок if y. работает. UPD нет, все равно не работает